# Convergence of series of product of sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose the positive series $\sum a_n$ converges. Does this imply that $\sum a_n \log a_n$ converges?

So, I think I have come up with a counterexample.
Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$. Then $\sum a_n$ converges, but $\sum a_n\log a_n$ does not make sense, because $\log a_n$ is undefined for negative values of $a_n$.

Now, I am unsure if my example satisfies $\sum a_n$ is a positive series. Does this mean that the terms of the sequence of partial sums are all positive (which it does satisfy), or that the terms of $a_n$ are all positive (in which case it does not hold and I am unsure where to go from here).

If it is the latter, then $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, but $\sum\log a_n$ diverges, so I still believe the implication is false, but I'm a little unsure of how to prove it.

Comment: "Positive series" is here intended to mean that the $a_i$ are positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\log n)^2}
$$
converges. (Using Cauchy condensation test)

While
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\log n)^2} \log \frac{1}{n (\log n)^2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{-\log n - 2\log\log n}{n (\log n)^2}
$$
does not. (Using Cauchy condensation test)

Comment: In this example, what is $a_n$? If $a_n=\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$, then I don't see how $\frac{1}{n\log n}=a_n\log a_n$.

Comment: @paygem The example still works. Only the second one needs to be modified.